# For $p$ prime and greater than 3, prove that $42p$ divides $3^p - 2^p - 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove the following:
$$42p \;|\; 3^p - 2^p - 1$$

$p$ is a prime number greater than 3.

I started working through my old olympiad problem books, but I couldn't solve this one.

Comment: Solution on page $8$ [here](https://ozgurmath.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/winter-camp.pdf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $a_p=3^p-2^p-1$

Check the case $p=7$ separately.  Excluding that case, we may assume that $2,3,7,p$ are pairwise distinct primes.

Step I: $\quad 2\,|\,a_p$  This is clear (odd+even +odd)

Step II:  $\quad 3\,|\,a_p$.  We have to show that $2^p\equiv -1 \pmod 3$ but this follows from the fact that $2\equiv -1 \pmod 3$ and $p$ is odd.

Step III:  $\quad 7\,|\,a_p$.  We remark that $p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6$ and that for either choice we have the desired divisibility.  Note: this is where we use the fact that $p>3$.

Step IV:  $\quad p\,|\,a_p$  We note that $a_p\equiv 3-2-1\equiv 0 \pmod p$

Inspection shows that we are done.